# IPA create fails, run build-ios-bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipa

I have followed the following tut:
https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1#11-creating-apps
to create the demo app hello world, only when Im trying to run the last command in the cli:

```
npm run build-ios-bundle -- --release --copy-to HalloWorld.ipa
```

Builds the project for iOS and produces an APP or IPA that you can manually deploy in the iOS Simulator or on device, respectively.
IMPORTANT: Before building for iOS device, verify that you have configured a valid pair of certificate and provisioning profile on your OS X system.

#### Options

child process exited with code 127
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ns-bundle" "--ios" "--build-app" "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ ns-bundle: `ns-bundle "HalloWorld.ipa"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ ns-bundle script 'ns-bundle "HalloWorld.ipa"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ns-bundle "HalloWorld.ipa"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Hugo/.npm/_logs/2017-04-12T14_47_59_306Z-debug.log
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build-ios-bundle" "--" "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build-ios-bundle: `npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build-ios-bundle script 'npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Hugo/.npm/_logs/2017-04-12T14_47_59_349Z-debug.log

Debug log

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok  
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node',  
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',  
1 verbose cli   'run',  
1 verbose cli   'build-ios-bundle',  
1 verbose cli   '--',  
1 verbose cli   '--release',  
1 verbose cli   '--copy-to',  
1 verbose cli   'HalloWorld.ipa' ]  
2 info using npm@4.2.0  
3 info using node@v7.9.0  
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild-ios-bundle',  
4 verbose run-script   'build-ios-bundle',  
4 verbose run-script   'postbuild-ios-bundle' ]  
5 info lifecycle @~prebuild-ios-bundle: @  
6 silly lifecycle @~prebuild-ios-bundle: no script for prebuild-ios-bundle, continuing  
7 info lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: @  
8 verbose lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true  
9 verbose lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/Hugo/Desktop/HelloWorld/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  
10 verbose lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: CWD: /Users/Hugo/Desktop/HelloWorld  
11 silly lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: Args: [ '-c',  
11 silly lifecycle   'npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"' ]  
12 silly lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: Returned: code: 1  signal: null  
13 info lifecycle @~build-ios-bundle: Failed to exec build-ios-bundle script  
14 verbose stack Error: @ build-ios-bundle: `npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"`  
14 verbose stack Exit status 1  
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)  
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)  
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)  
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)  
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)  
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)  
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)  
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)  
15 verbose pkgid @  
16 verbose cwd /Users/Hugo/Desktop/HelloWorld  
17 error Darwin 16.0.0  
18 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.9.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build-ios-bundle" "--" "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"  
19 error node v7.9.0  
20 error npm  v4.2.0  
21 error code ELIFECYCLE  
22 error errno 1  
23 error @ build-ios-bundle: `npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"`  
23 error Exit status 1  
24 error Failed at the @ build-ios-bundle script 'npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"'.  
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.  
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,  
24 error not with npm itself.  
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
24 error     npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app "--release" "--copy-to" "HalloWorld.ipa"  
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:  
24 error     npm bugs  
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:  
24 error     npm owner ls  
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.  
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can you please help me,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, switching back to node 6.11 works fine.